# Extract value from pandas data column where data is in dictionary format

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe df. In df I have a column student. Which contains data in this format

```
Students
{'id':1,'name':'Robin','class':2}
{'id':2,'name':'Thomas','class':3}
{'id':5,'name':'Marlon','class':9}
```

.....
It contains around 60 K rows in the data frame
I want to extract name from students & store in column Name
So I tried
df['name]=df['students'].iloc[0].get('name')
It works
Then I tried

```
l=len(df)
for i in range(0,l,1):
  df['name].iloc[i]=df['students'].iloc[i].get('name')
```

I got error message `float object does not have get method`
Can you help me to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess that maybe there is a cell whose entry is not a dictionary? This could be throwing the error.

I think I a more straightforward approach might be to use `lambda`, here I also try to check if the entry is a dictionary:

```
df['Name'] = df['Students'].apply(lambda x: x['name'] if type(x) is dict else np.nan)
```

Comment: If `isinstance(x, dict)`

Answer (score 0):

You can make a new DataFrame:

```
new_df = pd.DataFrame(df.Students.tolist())
print(new_df)
```

Prints:

```
   id    name  class
0   1   Robin      2
1   2  Thomas      3
2   5  Marlon      9
```